# how to overlay a line plot with a density plot? (R, ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi how do I overlap the following curves in one graph? Any help's appreciated. Thank you!

```
library(ggplot2)

x = -10:10
y = dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=3)
df.norm = data.frame('x'=x, 'y'=y)

ggplot(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point()

random = data.frame('x'=rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 3))

ggplot(random, aes(x=x)) + 
        geom_density(size=1)
```

I tried the following and it didn't work

```
ggplot(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point() +
        geom_density(random, aes(x=x), size=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

x = -10:10
y = dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=3)
df.norm = data.frame('x'=x, 'y'=y)

random = data.frame('x'=rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 3))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_density(data=random, aes(x=x), size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @scoa thank you so much! Can I ask a further question? How to add manually controlled legend? I tried this and didn't work... `ggplot() +
        geom_line(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y), colour='red') +
        geom_point(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y), colour='red') +
        geom_density(data=random, aes(x=x), size=1, colour='blue') 
        scale_colour_discrete(name  ="distribution",
                              labels=c('calculated', 'simulations')) ` thanks again!

Comment: just add colour statements *inside* `aes()` : `ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y,colour="red")) + 
  geom_point(data=df.norm, aes(x=x, y=y, colour='red')) + 
  geom_density(data=random, aes(x=x, colour='blue'), size=1) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name ="distribution", labels=c('calculated', 'simulations'))`

Answer (score 1):

**ggplot2**

A more concise version in ggplot2 using the argument `inherit.aes = FALSE` inside `geom_density` to override the default aesthetics used in the previous two layers.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2017)
x = -10:10
y = dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 3)
df.norm = data.frame('x' = x, 'y' = y)
random = data.frame('x' = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 3))

ggplot(data = df.norm, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_density(data = random,
               aes(x = x),
               inherit.aes = FALSE,
               size = 1)
```

[image]
**Base**

Adapting the solution provided by scoa to the base package:

```
plot(df.norm, type = "l", bty = "n", las = 1)
points(df.norm, pch= 19)
lines(density(random$x), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Adding a legend, and a different colour for the density curve:

```
plot(df.norm, type = "l", bty="n", las = 1)
points(df.norm, pch= 19)
lines(density(random$x), lwd =2, col = 'orange')
legend(x = "topleft", 
       c("df.norm", "Density plot"),
       col = c("black", "orange"),
       lwd = c(2, 2),
       bty = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mpalanco ! this is definitely useful. My ggplot2 often crashes Rstudio...how do you add legends please?

Comment: Great! @Y Zhang I edited my answer includind a legend. There are many arguments and options you can play with. Check the documentation typing `?legend`